# segmentation fault on accessing private instance variable c++

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault

I'm encountering a weird problem while working on `OpenCV`/`C++` project. I'm just trying to use `KNN` in the `ClassifierManager` class. For that reason, I'm using `cv::flann::Index * knnFlan` and it's initialized in the constructor as you can see below:

.h

```
class ClassifierManager
{
private:
    Mat dataToTrain;
    Mat classesData;
    int kNearestNeighborToConsider;
    CvKNearest *classifier;
    cv::flann::Index *knnFlan;

public:
    ClassifierManager();
    ClassifierManager(Mat trainData, Mat dataClasses, int numberOfNearestNeighborToConsider);
    vector < vector <int> > annotateTheTilesInImages(Mat trainData, vector < vector < vector <double> > > featuresPerImageForTiles, int numberOfNearestNeighborToConsider);
};
```

.m

```
ClassifierManager::ClassifierManager()
{}

ClassifierManager::ClassifierManager(Mat trainData, Mat dataClasses, int numberOfNearestNeighborToConsider)
{
//    dataToTrain = trainData;
//    classesData = dataClasses;
    kNearestNeighborToConsider = numberOfNearestNeighborToConsider;
    try
    {
        dataClasses.convertTo(dataClasses,CV_32FC1);
        trainData.convertTo(trainData,CV_32FC1);
        knnFlan = new flann::Index( trainData, flann::KDTreeIndexParams(1), cvflann::FLANN_DIST_EUCLIDEAN);
    } catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        cout << ex.what() << endl;
    }
}

vector < vector <int> > ClassifierManager::annotateTheTilesInImages( vector < vector < vector <double> > > featuresPerImageForTiles, int numberOfNearestNeighborToConsider)
{
    vector < vector <int> > resultForImagePerTile;
    for (int imageIndex = 0; imageIndex < featuresPerImageForTiles.size(); imageIndex++ )
    {
        vector < vector <double> >featuresPerTile = featuresPerImageForTiles[imageIndex];
        vector <int>  resultPerTile;
        for (int tileIndex = 0; tileIndex < featuresPerTile.size(); tileIndex ++)
        {
            vector <double> featureForTile = featuresPerTile[tileIndex];

            // estimate the response and get the neighbors' labels
            cv::Mat results, dists;
            Mat featureOfTileInMat(featureForTile);
            featureOfTileInMat.convertTo(featureOfTileInMat, CV_32FC1);
            featureOfTileInMat = featureOfTileInMat.t();
            //int result = classifier->find_nearest(featureOfTileInMat,numberOfNearestNeighborToConsider, &results, 0, &neighborResponses, &dists);
            //float percentageOfInstrumentForThisWindow = (float(countNonZero(neighborResponses)) / numberOfNearestNeighborToConsider) * 100;

            knnFlan->knnSearch(featureOfTileInMat, results, dists, numberOfNearestNeighborToConsider, flann::SearchParams());

              //..... Things to add


        }
    }

    return resultForImagePerTile;
}
```

main.m

```
/*Step 9: Knn Classifier train data */
Mat trainData = VectorUtility <double>::toMat(featuresPerTile);
Mat dataClasses = VectorUtility <int>::toMat(annotationPerTile);
ClassifierManager classifier(trainData, dataClasses, kNearestNeighbor);

/*Step 10: Annotation Step*/
vector < vector <int> > resultsForEachImagePerTile = classifier.annotateTheTilesInImages(trainData, featuresPerImageForTiles, kNearestNeighbor);
```

The problem is when I try to call `annotateTheTilesInImages` from the `main` the project crashes on the `knnFlan->knnSearch(featureOfTileInMat, results, dists, numberOfNearestNeighborToConsider, flann::SearchParams());` by throwing a `segmentation fault` which can't be catched by a try catch instruction. It seems to me there is a problem on how to manage the instance variables in the class but not sure what is it! Any help is appreciated.

**@updated above** just removing unnecessary code

**@Edited: The correct code:**

.h

```
class ClassifierManager
{
private:
    Mat dataToTrain;
    Mat classesData;
    int kNearestNeighborToConsider;
    CvKNearest *classifier;
    cv::flann::Index *knnFlan;

public:
    ClassifierManager();
    ClassifierManager(Mat &trainData, Mat &dataClasses, int numberOfNearestNeighborToConsider);
    vector < vector <int> > annotateTheTilesInImages(Mat trainData, vector < vector < vector <double> > > featuresPerImageForTiles, int numberOfNearestNeighborToConsider);
};
```

.m

```
ClassifierManager::ClassifierManager()
{}

ClassifierManager::ClassifierManager(Mat &trainData, Mat &dataClasses, int numberOfNearestNeighborToConsider)
{
    dataToTrain = trainData;
    classesData = dataClasses;
    kNearestNeighborToConsider = numberOfNearestNeighborToConsider;
    try
    {
        dataToTrain .convertTo(dataToTrain ,CV_32FC1);
        knnFlan = new flann::Index( dataToTrain , flann::KDTreeIndexParams(1), cvflann::FLANN_DIST_EUCLIDEAN);
    } catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        cout << ex.what() << endl;
    }
}

....
```

Comment: What is the value of `knnFlan` at that point?

Comment: It's a pointer.. how am I supposed to know its value? Also, it should contain an instance of cv::flann::Index (even if it was freed) so don't know if it really matters..

Comment: Please post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You're not initialising *any* members in your constructors (you're assigning to a couple, but not all, in the non-default one), and the default constructor is particularly bad. You should also follow the rule of three (or five or zero). Also, "it should contain an instance of cv::flann::Index (even if it was freed)" isn't true; if it was freed, the program is undefined.

Comment: @Maystro Pointers don't contain instances, ever - that's just not how pointers work. They can *point to* instances. By "what value does it contain" I mean does it contain NULL, or does it point to some instance of `cv::flann::Index`, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some more problems in code (for example, I don't see any place with `CvKNearest *classifier` initialization), but I suppose that your problem is caused by the following:

you pass `trainData` to `annotateTheTilesInImages` by *value*, not by *reference* or *constant reference*. It means that `trainData` inside this function is **another** object (with the same data, of course - **OpenCV** supports implicit sharing), but for `flann::Index` it can be an issue.

**EDIT:** I'm sorry, I mean you pass matrix by value to `ClassifierManager` constructor, not only to `annotateTheTilesInImages`. I. e. `cv::Mat` object that you passed to `flann::Index` constructor does not exist outside of `ClassifierManager` constructor (though data is still handled by other `cv::Mat` object).

Comment: Thanks... you're right.. The problem were in how I pass the trainData to the constructor.. I added clean code in the question.